# Amazon S3 policy to receive Daily SMS usage reports - not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sns

We have configured S3 bucket to receive Daily SMS usage reports from AWS SNS.

But the S3 bucket is not receiving any reports.

Here is policy we are using:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "sns-sms-daily-usage-policy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPutObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "sns.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowGetBucketLocation",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "sns.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: requires s3:ListBucket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test this, I did the following:

- Created an Amazon S3 bucket
- Applied the above Bucket policy (substituting my bucket name)
- In Amazon SNS, configured the SMS usage report to be delivered to this bucket
- Send an SMS
- **Waited two days**

The report finally appeared in my S3 bucket, called:

```
SMSUsageReports/ap-southeast-2/2018/10/31/001.csv.gz
```

The content was:

```
PublishTimeUTC,MessageId,DestinationPhoneNumber,MessageType,DeliveryStatus,PriceInUSD,PartNumber,TotalParts
2018-10-31T06:40:29.247Z,xxx,+61xxx,Promotional,Message has been accepted by phone,0.05878,1,1
```

So, it seems to take a long time to arrive, but it does arrive.

I also note that the first 100 SMS messages sent to a US number are free, so it is possible that free messages do not generate a usage report (but I used a non-US number, so I don't know whether this is the case).